# Normal puzzles vs puzzle rush performance on chess.com

Tags: tactics, puzzles, chess.com

I have been doing normal puzzles and puzzle rush on chess.com for the last 6 months. And I noticed that my performance in normal puzzles now jumped from 2100-2200 to 2400-2500. However, in puzzle rush, I still perform between 20-30 puzzles in 5 minutes without any noticeable improvement (like scoring more than 25). I'm still performing like low 20s and mid-20s sometimes, and rarely 29 or 30! I feel like I'm slow. It's true that I spend my time on normal puzzles: like I take 1-6 minutes (my average time is around 2-3 minutes) before I see the solution. I feel that normal puzzles improve concrete calculation skills, while puzzle rush improves pattern recognition in general and intuition for tactics without calculating deep enough. I would really appreciate some feedback on how to improve in puzzle rush because I think it can benefit my bullet skills.

Comment: Please note that your puzzle rush score on a given run is determined mainly by luck. If you get a bunch of bankrank mates at the beginning, you're in for a personal best!

Comment: I think this is what happened when I scored my 29 and 30!

Comment: I recommend survival mode unless you are intentionally doing blitz-like practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not very good at puzzle rush, but in principal it can be that 6 months are simply not enough to develop a complex skill. It is also not uncommon, that progress happens "in jumps", this has happened to me and was reported by others. You may try to give you another 6 months and then see what happens.

Keep in mind, that puzzle rush was invented by chess.com and is **not**  in line with old school recommendations, of how to improve in chess. Typically an old school GM will  [condem blitz playing](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=18555216) sharply.

Comment: I think the old school would be fine with the **survival mode** of puzzle rush.